# Using helper JS file to embed Typeform in Vue and Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm having an issue integrating a typeform into my website using vue and laravel.

The typeform gets embedded with a script, and Vue doesn't like it when I try to put the script directly inside the component, it throws this error:

> - Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.

Currently, I'm trying to inject it into the vue component using the Mounted() method. Here's my code:

```
 mounted() {
    var ts = document.createElement('script')
    ts.setAttribute('src','http://applyingawareness.com/public/js/typeformScripts/tf-merch.js');
    var tfDiv = document.getElementById('typeform');

    tfDiv.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',ts);

}
```

I placed the script at the specified Url in the `setAttribute` method, in my public/js directory. The issue is, it shows up as a 301 then a 404 when it's requested. Also, when I inspect the "sources" tab, the tf-merch.js file doesn't show up.

How do I load the typeform script (or any external script for that matter) into the dom so I can use it typeforms within my components?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to insert the script inside any divs handled by Vue, you could append the script to the body. You could probably also do this in the created() hook

```
let script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = 'http://applyingawareness.com/public/js/typeformScripts/tf-merch.js'
document.body.appendChild(script)
```